# Arduino IR Transmittor not working with my TV

Tags: c++, arduino

I try to do my DIY project with Arduino and IR transmitter. I connected and written code as per mentioned in web. but it is not working properly.

connections:

first IR pin connected to Ground

second IR pin connected to TX

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;
void setup() {}
void loop() {
    irsend.sendRC5(0x1FC1, 32);
    delay(5000);
}
```

This is my code in Arduino

for checking in serial monitor i used below code

```
#include <IRremote.h>
const int RECV_PIN = 2;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    if (results.decode_type == NEC) {
      Serial.print("NEC: ");
    } else if (results.decode_type == SONY) {
      Serial.print("SONY: ");
    } else if (results.decode_type == RC5) {
      Serial.print("RC5: ");
    } else if (results.decode_type == RC6) {
      Serial.print("RC6: ");
    } else if (results.decode_type == UNKNOWN) {
      Serial.print("UNKNOWN: ");
    }
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume();
  }
}
```

reference:  https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_IRremote.html

results- serial monitor:
from remote:                   RC5: 1FC1
from Arduino:                  RC5: 1FC1

both are same. but still my TV not working with Arduino but working with original remote

what could be the issue?

Comment: IR stands for "infra red", you can't visually "see" it with human eyes. You sent IR code `1FC1` and the Serial Monitor confirmed of receiving it, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Hi hcheung. thats correct. i tried to replicate my TV remote. codes are correct. but my tv not responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer, even it shows warning, I can control my TV and other by below code.
instead of RC5 I used NEC

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;
void setup() {}
void loop() {
    irsend.sendNEC(0x1FC1, 32);
    delay(5000);
}
```